# Button in tableviewcell doesn't show/hide as expected, upon scrolling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios6

I have a tableview with tableviewcell set to Custom in the Storyboard. I have 1 button at the further right of each cell (button in cell).

when loading each cell, depending on the condition, this button is supposed to show or hide. But it's not working as expected. As I scroll down and scroll up again, buttons that were previously hide (with correct condition) now are showing.

I do the same with image in the cell, and image is being loaded correctly even upon scrolling.

Here's my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIButton *btnCall = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    UIImageView *imgIcon = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:6];
    [btnCall setHidden:TRUE];


    if (... some condition ...) {
        [btnCall setHidden:false];
        [imgIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"]]; // load correctly
    } else {
        [btnCall setHidden:true]; // doesn't seem to work consistently.
        [imgIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2.png"]]; // load correctly
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In my Storyboard, this button in the prototype cell is also set to hidden.

I have read up a lot of the questions and answers regarding this issue.

- one is this [UIButton subview in UITableViewCell doesn't hide as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951439/uibutton-subview-in-uitableviewcell-doesnt-hide-as-expected). But mine is already a custom cell (set in Storyboard).
- another one: [iPhone TableViewCell - adding and removing button with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383305/iphone-tableviewcell-adding-and-removing-button-with-condition). But this requires creating button in the "if (cell == nil)" block, which I don't use. Cos if I use, all my other stuff (labels, images that are added to Custom cell through Storyboard) don't show up. And I really want to use the storyboard instead of adding items programmatically through the "if (cell == nil)" block.
- and others... but none worked so far.

I also have other things like image in each cell. And the images are loading correctly, even when scrolling up/down.

Can someone help please? Thanks a lot!

****EDIT 1 -- PROBLEM SOLVED!!! ****

I subclass my cell so that my resetting can be more proper. Here's how it's done (I replace the button above with an image instead - keep it as a button should work just fine too):

```
    @implementation PSCellMyTableViewCell

    @synthesize imgView1 = _imgView1, imgView2 = _imgView2;


    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.imgView1.image = nil;
        self.imgView2.image = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Code for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell1";
    PSCellMyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (... some condition ...) {
        [cell.imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-1.png"]];// no longer using tag
        [cell.imgView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-12.png"]]; // no longer using tag

    } else {
        [cell.imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-2.png"]];// no tag
        [cell.imgView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-22.png"]]; // no tag
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my own problem using this method: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells. Apparently, I didn't try hard enough from all the reading/googling (too tired I guess). So I decided to try subclassing my cell based on the mentioned reference. It works! (solution posted in my original post).